# Angular 6 can not change host value

Tags: angular, angular6

I wanted to ask you about the new `angular.json` file which replaced the `.angular-cli.json`.

I used to override the host value there, but now i can not find how to override it. Does anyone has run into the same problem?

Can you suggest me a solution other than writing host as parameter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can implement them on "projects" -> "coreui-angular" -> "serve" ->  "options" path in angular.json

[image]